# js how can I get the source css rule in getComputedStyle rule

Tags: javascript, styles, rules, getcomputedstyle

as we know that with window.getComputedStyle() method we can get the computed styles of specific element. (see https://jsfiddle.net/r7sgpyt5/1/).
My question is,how can we know where the CSSStyleDeclaration in the computed style come from.for example in https://jsfiddle.net/r7sgpyt5/1/ I have define a css rule like:

```
#element{
  color:red;
  border:1px solid #999;
  margin:10px;
}
```

if I use getComputedStyle(element,null).getPropertyValue("color") it returns "rgb(255, 0, 0)",but how can I know the property "color" is defined in the css selector "#element".

Thx!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to? I don't think there is a way, other than parsing CSS files.

Comment: Because I want to update the css rule,so I need know which CSSStyleDeclaration to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tsingbo, as far as I know it's impossible, but you can try window.getMatchedCSSRules in Chrome.